# How to show Image programmatically in custom alert dialog

Tags: java, android

When you click on button camera should open After capturing the image it should show in customAlertDialog with two options save and cancel

here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
Button photo;
static final int REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE = 1;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    photo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_photo);

    photo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
                startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            }
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_IMAGE_CAPTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
        Bitmap imageBitmap = (Bitmap) extras.get("data");
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Could you add your code to try ?

Comment: i have added my code ..please help me i am new to android

Comment: create new layout for alert box and apply that layout to alert box and u r done :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this call from where you want to call camera::

```
 Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, 101);
```

When you come back after capturing picture from camera. It will call "onActivityResult()" and do code like this:

```
 public void onActivityResult(int requestcode,int resultcode,final Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestcode, resultcode, intent);
    if (resultcode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (requestcode == 101) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //Do nothing here. Because image is already saved but if you want to save it other place then do code.
                }
            }).setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                {
                    //Do here code for for deleting image using uri
                }
            });
            final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.go_pro_dialog_layout, null);
            dialog.setView(dialogLayout);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            dialog.show();

            final ImageView image = (ImageView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.goProDialogImage);
            Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");
            image.setImageBitmap(photo); //Edited here





        }
    }
}
```

Now create a XML layout name as "go_pro_dialog_layout.xml"

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/goProDialogImage"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here you are done with whole code..and happy coding.

Comment: Bitmap mImageBitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), Uri.parse(mCurrentPhotoPath));

i am unable to get (this.getContentResolver()) and once please check my code ,i am getting bitmap result how to convert it to Uri

Comment: Bitmap photo = (Bitmap) intent.getExtras().get("data");

intent is not resolving.......please help me and icon(in layout params) ..sorry for asking such type of questions ...i am new here hope you understand.

Comment: Thankyou soo much. if need more help ask for.

Comment: i need your support can you message me in watsapp 9550534541